# Place order button translate title

Tags: checkout

i have few languages in my magento shop, but in checkout in last step button Place order always in all store without translate, in csv files present translation but not working, in file button.phtml in app/design/frontend/default/theme193k/template/checkout/onepage/review have code:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?>" class="button btn-checkout" onclick="review.save()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?></span></span></button>
```

how make translate for this button? in developer mode - through Frontend translate inline - also - translate not allow, can you help me translate this button

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Make sure that you have refresh you `Cache` form the `System >> Cache Management`.

If all done then make sure then you have install the all store language Packs.

If above all checks done then Still you are facing problem then you have to create translation file for each language in your theme `locale` folder using below steps.

I assume that your store in french language.

**Step 1:** Create `locale` folder in current theme folder.

**Step 2:** Create `fr_FR` same name as in `app\locale` which language pack used.

**Step 3:** Create `translate.csv` in that folder.

**Step 4:** Added the `"Place Order","Passer une commande"` & Save the file.

**Step 5:** Refresh the cache again and Check your page.

Let me know if any comment.

Comment: My pleasure :)....